# How to disable VCPKG for a specific target in CMake

Tags: cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to disable VCPKG for a specific target in my Cmake project using `VS_GLOBAL_VcpkgEnabled` .

```
add_library(manager SHARED)
target_sources(manager PRIVATE "src/manager.cpp" "src/manager.h")
set_target_properties(manager PROPERTIES VS_GLOBAL_VcpkgEnabled FALSE)
# other properties...
```

However, it is still using the `vcpkg` toolchain. Could someone kindly let me know how `vcpkg` can be temporarily turned off? In Visual Studio, by right-clicking on the project, `vcpkg` can be disabled for a specific project. I would like to do the same thing in a `CMakeLists.txt`.